# If $(X,T)$ is a topological space, are all element of $T$ homeomorphic to $X$?

Tags: general-topology

I know that all open set $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Is this property true in all topological space ? I mean, if $(X,T)$ is a topological space, then all element $U\in T$ are homeomorphic to $X$?

Comment: No. If you take a discrete topology for example then all points are open, but they are not homeomorphic to the whole space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't know that, since it is not true. For instance, $(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ is *not* homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm really astonished, I thought in a manifold, being locally homeomorphic to an $\mathbb R$ and having a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ where equivalent...

Comment: @Henri But they **are** equivalent. What has that to do with my answer or with your question?

Comment: @Henri the spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ have a base of open sets that are homeomorphic to the whole space, but not *all* non-empty open sets are.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Sorry, I didn't want to offense you. Your answer is a good one (and very helpfull) :) I was confused, thank you.

Comment: @Henri Offense me?! No, you did not.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Take the simplest possible case: a set with two members, {a, b} and the "discrete topology", {{},{a},{b}, {a,b}}.  Two of the sets in the topology contain only one member while the entire space contains two members.

In fact, your original statement "all open set U in $R^n$ is homeomorphic to $R^n$" is NOT true! One of the opens sets is the **empty** set and the empty set is definitely not homeomorphic to $R^n$.